# Sparse matrices dot multiplication

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, sparse-arrays, gpu

I have two huge sparse matrices, and I am interested in dot multiplication them. But I have a memory issue so a notebook is a shutdown. I am using the 11.3 version.
Any suggestion on how to avoid memory issues.

Edit:

```
n = 30000;
m = 22000000;
mat = SparseArray[
   RandomInteger[{1, n}, {m, 2}] -> RandomReal[{0, 1}, m], {n, n}];
mat2 = SparseArray[
   mat["NonzeroPositions"] -> 
    RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length@mat["NonzeroPositions"]], 
   Dimensions[mat]];
```

Comment: Running `mem = N[MaxMemoryUsed[res = mat.mat;]/2^20]` tells me that this needs less than 80 MB. So this will hardly make modern hardware collapse (this would also run und my old RaspberryPi 2...) Is your actual matrix larger than this?

Comment: Should the actual matrices be too large, one has to avoid matrix-matrix multiplication to to rephrase everything into matrix-vector mutiplications. For example, `u` being a vector, instead of `res.u`, you should use `mat.(mat.u)`. This might bring also a considerable speed-improvement, if only few of results of the form `res.u` are needed. I gets more complicated when `res` has to enter a linear system which you want to solve. But if you cannot build `res`, then you cannot solve the system with direct methods anyways. So you would have to switch to (preconditoned!) iterative methods.

Comment: ... and for these iterative methods (e.g. GMRES), you need only matrix-vector multiplication. So also in that case, you can go with `mat.(mat.u)`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you. Hmmm yes, it is the real size of my matrix....I am working under Win and this calculation collapse my notebook

Comment: Of course, it really depends on the structure of the nonzero values, not only on the size. Please, can you show me the code to generate the actual matrix?

Comment: Are you sure that both matrices that you dot-multiply, are sparse? If one is dense, then the product will be coerced to a sense matrix. If the dense matrix is of size $k \times n$ and the sparse matrix is of size $n \times m$ with $k n \ll n m$, then the product will be a dense $k \times m$ matrix and may not fit into memory although each factor fits.

Comment: If Mathematica is repeatedly crashing, it might be worth restarting your computer.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, I made a mistake I didn't answer correctly to our question about the size of the matrix. My matrix is a square matrix with 34000 dimensions and ~22000000 non-zero values. I have two matrices with equivalent non zero position, and I am interested in dividing one by another. I edit the example code in the question.

Comment: Dot products of two sparse matrices (unless they are very sparse) will result in a SparseArray representation of a dense matrix (this will cause a memory issue). Division on the other hand has a divide by 0 issue, but should not have a memory issue.

Comment: @KirilDanilchenko So your matrices have about 2% of nonzeros. By many people, this is not considered as a really sparse matrix. Note that it is not uncommon that the product of two sparse matricies has a significantly greater density (number of nonzero values devided by the total numer of entries). This is one of the cases. In order to develop an efficient method, you have to avoid computing the product of the two. And as Carl pointed out: Using the inverse of a sparse matric has also better to be avoided.

Comment: So the real art in numerical mathematics and programming is to circumvent such bottlenecks. It is also not uncommon that this rules out whole classes of approaches (usually the straight-forward methods) to solve a specific problem. So, welcome in the world of numerical mathematics! ;)

Comment: @CarlWoll A matrix needs to be _that_ dense to produce a dense product. Please see the example below.

Answer (score 1):

More an extended comment than an answer.

Many of us are used to obtain a quite sparse matrix from the matrix product of two sparse matrices. That's is maybe because we are used to obtain sparse arrays as the system matrices of differential equations where each degree of freedom interacts with only few other degrees of freedoms or as adjacency matrices of more or less random graphs. But actually, it suffices to have *one* degree of freedom in the system (or a vertex that is connected to all other vertices in the graph) in order to obtain a completely dense matrix from a multiplication of a matrix with itself as the following example shows:

```
n = 10000;
A = SparseArray[{}, {n, n}];
A[[1, All]] = 1;
A[[All, 1]] = 1;
A["Density"]
B = A.A;
B["Density"]
```

> 0.00019999
>
> 1.

Comment: This is in part because no sparsification is done along the way, e.g. To see if a different background value might work. But your point remains valid, and random values would force a dense matrix there. For many purposes, it can be better to defer matrix-times-matrix altogether, and instead iterate matrix-times-vector.